# How to stop inno installer to change the current page?

Tags: inno-setup

I am playing some video while installing the application. So wpFinish page has to appear only when the user agrees to it there by letting the user to finish the video. But in my case wpFinish page shows as soon as installation finished.

Comment: How do you show the video ? has the component you are using a video finished event ?